# Which apps offer picture in picture on the iPad with iOS 9?

Tags: ipad, video, ios

I want to try watching a movie while using other apps.

Do you know which movie apps will let me do that?

The only one I know of us Instapaper, which does PiP for YouTube and Vimeo videos.

Comment: Possibly off topic? are you asking for a recommendation?

Comment: @Schwertspize I don't need a recommendation. I just want to see how this key feature of iOS nine is implemented. And I want to try it out.

Comment: Oh....  OK, sorry I'm not an ios device owner and don't know this is possible since ios 9.

Comment: @Schwertspize yeah, it's one of the headline features of iOS 9 for iPad. The problem is, that not many video creators are enabling it. So, I'm trying to see who has it now.